# Why does it take longer to iterate over the column of a R data frame than to iterate over an equivalent vector?

Tags: r, dataframe, performance, vector

I work with a large data frame in R (containing 2310000 rows)

I found that a loop that iterate directly on the elements of the data frame column can be very slow. I compared this to iterating on the elements of a vector of equivalent size :

```
df = data.frame(matrix(0, nrow = 2310000, ncol = 1))

t0 = Sys.time()

# iterating on data frame
df$var = 0
for (i in 1:100) {
  df$var[i] = 1
}

t1 = Sys.time()

# iterating on vector
df$var = 0
v_var = df$var
for (i in 1:100) {
  v_var[i] = 1
}
df$var = v_var

t2 = Sys.time()

print(t1 - t0) ; print(t2 - t1)
```

Output :

> Time difference of 0.1035166 secs

> Time difference of 0.0075109 secs

Can someone explain me why iterating on the elements of a large data frame is slower ?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

First, to set the stage and show that it's not only extraction from a data.frame that is happening - let's compare the speed of this operation across different object types:

```
library(microbenchmark)

df  = data.frame(matrix(0, nrow = 2310000, ncol = 1))
df$var = 0

lst = as.list(df)
mat = data.matrix(df)


microbenchmark(
  in_df = for (i in 1:100) {
    df$var[i] = 1
  },
  in_mat = for (i in 1:100) {
    mat[i,"var"] = 1
  },
  in_lst = for (i in 1:100) {
    lst$var[i] = 1
  }
)

Unit: milliseconds
   expr        min         lq       mean     median         uq        max neval
  in_df 223.218706 248.705949 293.525415 274.549170 336.379693 394.847852   100
 in_mat   1.304793   1.639721   1.932387   1.841773   2.086342   3.612089   100
 in_lst   1.571596   1.705783   2.076625   2.005105   2.316363   5.913198   100
```

As you can see, matrix and lists didn't have any problems. data.frame is also a list under the hood. So what is going on here? The answer can be found in reading the help manual for the data.frame dollar replacement function:

```
help(`$<-.data.frame`)

  [...]

  There is no ‘data.frame’ method for ‘$’, so ‘x$name’ uses the
  default method which treats ‘x’ as a list (with partial matching
  of column names if the match is unique, see ‘Extract’).  The
  replacement method (for ‘$’) checks ‘value’ for the correct number
  of rows, and replicates it if necessary.

  [...]
```

So this tells us that, unlike in the case of list, when assigning to a column of a data.frame we also have to make sure that the length of assignment matches the number of rows in the data.frame. This is because a data.frame is a special kind of list - a list where all elements have the same length so it could be arranged into a table format.

You can look at everything the method for data.frame does by inspecting this code:

```
 > `$<-.data.frame`
function (x, name, value) 
{
    cl <- oldClass(x)
    class(x) <- NULL
    nrows <- .row_names_info(x, 2L)
    if (!is.null(value)) {
        N <- NROW(value)
        if (N > nrows) 
            stop(sprintf(ngettext(N, "replacement has %d row, data has %d", 
                "replacement has %d rows, data has %d"), N, nrows), 
                domain = NA)
        if (N < nrows) 
            if (N > 0L && (nrows%%N == 0L) && length(dim(value)) <= 
                1L) 
                value <- rep(value, length.out = nrows)
            else stop(sprintf(ngettext(N, "replacement has %d row, data has %d", 
                "replacement has %d rows, data has %d"), N, nrows), 
                domain = NA)
        if (is.atomic(value) && !is.null(names(value))) 
            names(value) <- NULL
    }
    x[[name]] <- value
    class(x) <- cl
    return(x)
}
<bytecode: 0x7fd0667fce80>
<environment: namespace:base>
```

One solution to bypass this is to temporary transform your data.frame into a list, and then transform back.

```
microbenchmark(
  in_df = {
    df <- unclass(df)
    in_df = for (i in 1:100) {
      df$var[i] = 1
    }
    df <- list2DF(df)
  }
)

Unit: milliseconds
  expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
 in_df 5.575034 5.938803 7.471679 5.988667 7.090439 16.38276   100
```

Or, if all your data is of the same time, store it in a matrix instead of a data.frame.

Answer (score 0):

Your first for loop consists of two steps. For each i:

- You first subset `df` (`df$var`)
- You then change a value in this vector `(df$var)[i] = 1`

These steps are performed 100 times.

In your second for loop there is only one operation in the for loop:

- You change a value in the vector `v_var` (`v_var[i] = 1`)

You also do some operations outside the for loop, but because these are done once rather than 100 times, they have a negligible impact on the total time.

I used the `microbenchmark` package to demonstrate this:

```r
library(microbenchmark)

df = data.frame(matrix(0, nrow = 23100, ncol = 1))

# iterating on data frame
df$var = 0
v_var = df$var

microbenchmark(
  in_df = for (i in 1:100) {
    df$var[i] = 1
  },
  outside_df = {
    v_var = df$var
    for (i in 1:100) {
      v_var[i] = 1
    }
    df$var = v_var
  },
  access_df = for (i in 1:100) {
    df$var
  }
)
#> Unit: milliseconds
#>        expr       min        lq     mean    median       uq       max neval
#>       in_df 21.507375 23.080368 34.24766 26.196194 30.23929 239.06351   100
#>  outside_df 11.200713 12.008956 14.52469 13.312613 14.74701  74.32721   100
#>   access_df  8.769038  9.204913 10.35766  9.983931 10.78568  17.01080   100
```

We measure three things here:

- `in_df` is your first for loop.
- `outside_df` is your second for loop.
- `access_df` is the time taken to access `df$var` 100 times.

Note that ignoring some outliers, the time taken by `in_df` is approximately the time

Comment: I think this answer is still missing something. The two operations even when added together take less time compared with "in_df".

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I am not convinced : using the same block of code but with a data frame of 2310000 rows, the mean time for in_df, outside_df and access_df are respectively 196, 6 and 1 ms.

Then, access_df is not responsible for the difference between in_df and outside_df.

It seems that modifying df adds extra computation, as pointed by @KarolisKoncevičius